# What could go wrong if one ignored weak entities during database modelling?

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I never use weak entities when I'm doing database modelling and things seems fine till now. I usually ignored the whole issue by giving each entity a primary (auto generated) key.

However, I came across some [posts](http://www.siue.edu/~dbock/cmis450/3-ermodel.htm) that mention that some entities should be weak if their existence totally depends on other entities.

But on the other hand, some refer to weak entities as a set which does not possess sufficient attributes to form a primary key. Well that means all entities in my database where weak at first before I gave them the auto incremented key.

Could someone please outline the importance of weak entities and what are the consequences of not using them? Why don't we just give each entity a primary auto generated key and make it strong?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe someone can explain why weak entities should be identified by the primary key of the parent entity + an identifier instead of creating a surrogate key and relating it to the parent entity using a foreign key (with cascading changes on update and delete)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an order with multiple order line items as an example.  The weak entities would be the individual line items stored in their own table.  Their primary key could be the primary key of the order, plus a simple integer number (e.g. 1, 2, 3, which is unique only within the order.)  Thus, they don't really have their own primary key as a unique numbered column, their key spans two columns and is only unique that way.

The order line items should be deleted if and when the order is deleted - they don't make sense standing on their own.  It is this linkage that makes them weak -- one thing being deleted should delete the other.

If you give each order line item their own primary key, you'll still need to relate them back to the order item, which means putting in a foreign key for the order item or, having a cross reference table.  (You may also need to know the line item number from the order, which would mean adding a simple integer column...  and at this point you've added enough to have a key without an auto generated one.) For the design pattern of owned sub items, either of these alternatives is a bit of overkill.

Using the complex primary key also enforces the relationship between order and line order items, in that this schema will not allow you cannot have a line item assigned to multiple orders.

Another consideration is that you can shard the orders and order line items according to the order item primary key, since both tables have that key.  (Sharding is generally easier to do based on the primary key than regular columns.)

---

Hierarchical containment isn’t always what you want; but, it is such a commonly occurring pattern that it is nice to be clear about it, and composite keys can be used in this case.  Here, using order items with line items as sub-items (i.e. contained), we’re saying not just that line items are 1 to many with respect an order, but that line items are owned and don’t exist independently of orders — that line items compose to create a single order object.

In keeping with that, we’re explicitly not going to manage a separate key space for (all) line items (together as a group), but instead borrow and extend the key space of an order.  Instead of asking the system to maintain a separate key space for line items, and manually (i.e. less formally) maintaining a foreign key relation back to the order, and also maintaining an integer line item rather separately (from the order foreign reference), we can ask the system to ensure uniqueness of the whole composite key, which includes the line item number within the order.

Of course, you wouldn’t be able to add a line item that isn’t associated with an order, but additionally, using the composite sub-key, you also won’t be able to add one that overlaps with another (e.g. it won’t let you add two line item #3’s for the same order).

This forces producers and consumers of line items to think about them as being contained within and part of orders, and not as independent items, or, put another way, to reference a line item by going thru an order, or, yet in other words, to get a reference to the order “for free” by referencing one of its line items.  (And because you also have a reference to the order as part of such a foreign key, you can also use that order portion of the composite foreign key alone to group or join.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm glad you mentioned the **Orders** and **lines** example because I'm working on an ordering system that is modeled exactly like you explained. Both `Orders` and `lines` tables have a surrogate primary key which are `order_id` and `line_id` respectively. The `lines` table has a **non null-able** foreign key `fk_order_id` pointing to the `order_id` and is configured for cascade update and delete. I fail to see why in this case specifically using a composite key is better??

Comment: Using a composite key enforces the sub-item relationship, and announces it to both the dbms (e.g. for sharding) and to other users (clients who may store the key, including other tables).  The former means better dbms scale out, and regarding the latter, use of composite key makes (other table’s) foreign keys for line items into implicit references connected to the owning order.  This results in a stronger schema that is usually preferred for the sub-item pattern.

Comment: "_use of composite key makes (other table’s) foreign keys for line items into implicit references connected to the owning order._"  I'm not sure that I understood that part completely. Could you please update your **Order has lines** example to further elaborate on that point. I have a feeling that this is the point that I have been looking for.

Comment: To be sure, there are arguments to be made in both directions as to whether this is good or not, much of it going to the quality of tooling support for composite keys, some of that in SQL itself, and some in tooling (e.g. OR mapping).

Comment: Thanks for the update :) I think I'm starting to see where weak entities can shine. I think using weak entities is more of a good design decision than an actual implementation need. What I'm trying to say is I used to promote all weak entities to strong ones and everything worked like a charm. Moreover I read 2 database modelling books [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201752840) & [Database Modeling and Design](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Modeling-Design-Fifth-Management/dp/0123820200)...(continued)

Comment: (continued)...one of them didn't mention weak entities and the other just hinted it. Can I conclude from this that using weak entities isn't common and people often opt for promoting them to strong ones like mentioned [here](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0CE8QFjAFOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fokaram.spsu.edu%2F~curri%2Fclasses%2F12%2Fspring-12%2FDB%2FStudyNotes%2FCh3-AdvancedER%2FAdvancedERModeling.pdf&ei=agbqUNEGi8u0Bp3hgNAG&usg=AFQjCNHmM6aKXEKroTZfzS9chHg-VyoIVQ&sig2=cGoUqjfNNCgbRTXJl965Bg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms)?

Comment: I'd agree; probably want to think of certain data as exhibiting hierarchical containment, but it's a design decision as to how implement as there are a number of different ways, and add to that there is valid debate found pro and con about composite keys (they are even more controversial in contexts without the hierarchical concerns in this topic).  And YMMV based on what you want to enforce strongly in the db vs. what might be done in the app or a service layer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a project that had to manage large amounts of data samples for lake readings. In this project, we had tables similar to the following, where `records` is a collection of lake readings by location and uploader, and `samples` contain the actual lake readings -- things like temperature and intensity.

```
CREATE TABLE records(
    email TEXT REFERENCES users(email),
    lat DECIMAL,
    lon DECIMAL,
    depth TEXT,
    upload_date TIMESTAMP,
    comment TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (upload_date,email)
);

CREATE TABLE samples(
    date_taken TIMESTAMP,
    temp DECIMAL,
    intensity DECIMAL,
    upload_date TIMESTAMP,
    email TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(date_taken,upload_date,email),
    FOREIGN KEY (upload_date,email) REFERENCES records(upload_date,email)
);
```

`samples` was modeled as a weak entity, dependent on `records`. As you know, this means that all of the foreign keys are inherited from `records` and used to identify a single row in `samples`.  But what would happen if we decided to make it an entity instead? Well, you can look at it a few different ways, Either:

1. The primary key from `records` would not be present in `samples` and
   we would have to assign some kind of arbitrary auto increment type
   ID, as you suggest. Each record contains thousands of samples, and users think of
   samples as part of the records that they recorded in the field. They
   expect to browse samples by record, so we would have a very large
   `samples` table with no obvious mapping to the records they belong
   to in real life.
2. Or we simply don't *model* it as a weak entity, but recognize that
   it needs to be able to identify itself with a `records` row, so we
   assign an `upload_date` and `email`. If we make these two entries
   foreign keys, then we have just made a weak entity without realizing
   it. If we don't, then our application layer has to be responsible
   for checking to make sure that each `upload_date` and `email` are
   also present in `records`, instead of the database doing it.

In this case, making `samples` a weak entity (including foreign keys in its primary key) is the simplest option (and makes the most sense).

**Summary**

You should model entities as weak when they are actually weak in real life. If you have an entity that needs a portion of a different key to identity itself (having a foreign key that is part of its primary key), then its probably weak.

Can you remodel the system to avoid using weak entities? Possibly, if we wanted to have unassociated samples, then we would need to be able to make their `upload_date` and `email` null, which means they would not be in the primary key and would not be a weak entity. We would have to do something like I described in 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is something that I don't understand though. In point 2 _ If we make these two entries foreign keys, then we have just made a weak entity without realizing it_... How come this is equivalent to making a composite primary key of the parent key and a child's identifier?

Comment: Well, that is pretty much the definition of a Weak Entity. In the post you linked, they say _one entity cannot exist unless there is an occurrence of a related entity_, and the way we represent this in a database is with a composite primary/foreign key. So if we have columns that are foreign keys, and also part of a primary key, then that table is a weak entity by definition. Remember, primary key attributes cannot be null, and primary keys identify rows, so when foreign keys are in primary keys, the identity of that row must depend on the tables referenced in the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key must be unique. Forever. That's all there is to it. If the data in the table doesn't provide that naturally you'd create a surrogate key.

Now what are those. A natural key consists of one or more existing columns, whereas a surrogate key is an extra added column, usually auto-incremental.

A good example for a natural key would be an ISO country code in a `countries` table. You'd gain nothing from adding an auto-increment column here. On the contrary, you may save yourself from JOINing in the countries table in some queries, because you already have the ISO code right there.

A bad one, the name (or multiple columns) in a `contacts` table. That's why it's better to use a surrogate key in this case.

That's how i think about it and i rarely - if ever - run into any kind of questionable layout issues.

A practical hint: you never run an `UPDATE` on columns making up the primary key. You'd delete that row and re-insert it with new values. That can save you a lot of headaches.